# Nodejs - cannot find module (Docker)

Tags: node.js, docker

Trying to test out multistage builds in Docker for my nodejs app and I keep running into

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/service/dist/server/server.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM mybaseimage as dev
WORKDIR /service

COPY src ./src
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./

# This is required to build native modules
# https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md#node-gyp-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    g++ \
    make \
    py3-pip

# Not clearing the cache here saves us time in the next step
RUN yarn install \
    && yarn compile

# Re-use the dev container to create a production-ready node_modules dir
FROM dev AS build
WORKDIR /service

RUN rm -rf /service/node_modules\
    && yarn install --production=true \
    && yarn cache clean

FROM mybaseimage AS prod
WORKDIR /service

COPY --from=build /service/dist/ .
COPY --from=build /service/node_modules/ .

# https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/docs/BestPractices.md#handling-kernel-signals
RUN apk add --no-cache dumb-init


EXPOSE 5678
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD ["node", "dist/server/server.js"]
```

My `package.json`

```
"serve": "node dist/server/server.js",
"start": "concurrently \"docker-compose up\" \"yarn watch\"",
```

My earlier working Dockerfile was

```
FROM mybaseimage

#set working directory
WORKDIR /service

# Copy the needed files into the container
COPY src ./src
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./

RUN apk update
RUN apk add python3
RUN echo python3 --version
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn compile


EXPOSE 5678
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the final stage, you are `COPY`ing the `dist` and `node_modules` trees from the build stage into the current directory.  You need to explicitly state the subdirectory names on the right-hand side of `COPY`.

```bash
COPY --from=build /service/dist/ ./dist/
COPY --from=build /service/node_modules/ ./node_modules/
```

Also see the [Dockerfile reference on `COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy): since the `COPY` source is a directory, the *contents* of the directory are copied to the destination and not the directory itself.  This differs from the normal Unix `cp` or `mv` commands.

You should be able to verify this running a debugging container on top of your built image; for example

```bash
docker run --rm your-image ls
```

should show the `server` subdirectory from the build `dist` tree, as well as all of the individual installed Node packages, all directly in the image's `/service` directory and not in subdirectories.

Comment: Wow this fixed it. Thanks for the detailed and clear explanation